# CoffeeScript - Unmatched OUTDENT

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I've been trying to pass my working javascript code into CoffeeScript but i can't get pass this error:

> unmatched OUTDENT on line 55

This is the coffeescript code

```
$(document).on("click",".save_button", ->
    $form = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()
    $form.bind("ajax:complete", ->
                $actionURI = $form.attr("action");
        $.get(window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+$actionURI+".js",(data) ->
                    $form.parent().parent().prev().html(data); //Line 55
                    closeSaveElement()
        ,"html")
    );
    $form.submit();   
    return false;
);
```

i've tried putting and erasing `;` everywhere but i don't whats wrong. I also tried to change `->` for `=>` but the same error pops up.

Comment: http://www.coffeelint.org/ is a helpful tool to keep your CofeeScript clean

Comment: http://js2coffee.org/ is my favorite for Coffee / JS

Comment: @JasonSperske coffeelint seems a bit outdated tho

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()`: Wow. I take it you don't know about [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valid JS isn't really valid CoffeeScript. You'd have to do something like this:

```
$(document).on "click", ".save_button", ->
    $form = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()

    $form.bind "ajax:complete", ->
        $actionURI = $form.attr "action"
        $.ajax
            type: "get"
            url: "#{window.location.protocol}//#{window.location.host}#{$actionURI}.js"
            dataType: "html"
            success: ->
                $form.parent().parent().prev().html(data)
                closeSaveElement()

    $form.submit()

    return false
```

Also, do something about this line:

```
$form = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()
```

`.closest()` should be helpful.

Comment: hey thanks, yeah i don't like at all the whole parent() thing, let me check out closest(). So what i'm seeing, i should remove all traces of ;

Comment: Well also whitespace is important for coffeescript.  It indicates things like the beginning and ending of functions, hash blocks, etc.  So where you indent `$actionURI = $form.attr("action")` - this could cause a problem (not to mention the semicolon).