# Why am I getting *unmatched OUTDENT* in this haml template in Rails 4.2 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

[image]I've been playing with react-rails gem and so I made a sample application with haml.  When I do `rails s` and go to my sample route, I see the attached error coming from application.html.haml, the standard layout/application.html.haml view in Rails 4.2.  If I remove *stylesheet_link_tag* and *javascript_include_tag* the Rails view renders fine.  What could be causing it?  Below are the relevant files.  There is also a sample.coffee file but I can't imagine that has anything to do with it since as soon as I remove the **_tag* helpers the Rails view renders without error.

*application.js.coffee*

```
# This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
# listed below.
#
# Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
# or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
#
# It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
# compiled file.
#
# Read Sprockets README (https:#github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
# about supported directives.
#
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs

#= require react
#= require react_ujs
#= require components
#= require_tree .
```

*application.html.haml*

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %title SampleApp
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
```

*application.css*

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

*Gemfile*

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.6.0'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'httparty'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'lol_dba', require: false
gem 'foreman'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
group :development do
  gem 'sextant'
  gem 'awesome_print', require: false
  gem 'hirb', require: false
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'flog', require: false
  gem 'flay', require: false
  gem 'reek', require: false
  gem 'derailed'
  gem 'stackprof'
  gem 'sandi_meter'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'pry'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'codeclimate-test-reporter', require: nil
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma'
end
```

Comment: Did you run `rails g react:install` before?

Comment: Yes I ran that command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoffeeScript - Unmatched OUTDENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325872/coffeescript-unmatched-outdent)